# Numeric separators in GIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, decimal-points, spanish

In Spanish and Catalan, we use numeric separators the other way round: We use a comma instead of the decimal point; and a point instead of a comma to mark the thousands.

```
English | Spanish
   10.5      10,5
2,228     2.228
1,150.2   1.150,2
```

What precautions have to be taken when transferring geographic data between programs configured in different languages?

Is there a way to force programs to emit all numeric values in English, and expect them in the same language?

Is there a way to do the same using Spanish as the standard?

Right now, I'm working with PostGIS and GeoServer, but I expect to use other programmes in the short term: mainly ArcGIS Server and Sitmun.

Comment: how are you transfering your data, most programs use a binary representation

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused question/Best answer model operates. Unfortunately, this question is somewhat generic and more open-ended than most questions that aren't closed as either *too-broad* or *discussion-based*.

Comment: @Ian. I'm not sure. I tell GeoServer to get data from PostGIS. I do it through a graphical interface. One instance of GeoServer runs on an English version of Windows and gets the map correctly. The other one runs on a Spanish version of Windows and doesn't get the map right. So I suspected that there might be something going on with the language configuration.

Comment: Most technical specifications here are defined outside of any human language; e.g. if you mix symbols in WKT (i.e. `LINESTRING(0,3 0,3. 1,5 1,5)`) you will screw up your data. The answer thus is "None", since there is a well defined syntax for every programming language or data format that you have to follow. Your concerns might be directed at the presentation of data e.g. on maps, though, but then it's a matter of string interpretation.

Comment: I think you'd be better off describing the way you set up the two servers and what the error messages are before jumping to a conclusion

Comment: @IanTurton. I don't know how much detail should I give, there. To explain everything I remember, I might well fill a few pages. And the problem might lay in something I don't remember, or even that someone else did. The GeoServer on Spanish Windows has been there for years; well before I started working for the company.

Comment: I would use decimal points everywhere in the system and commas only when data are presented for humans.